# I.V.P. : $ x^2 z_x + y^2 z_y = z^2 \; ; \; z=1 $ on the initial curve $C : y=2x $

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, characteristics

**Exercise :**

> Solve the Initial Value Problem (I.V.P.)
>   $$\begin{cases} 
> x^2 z_x + y^2 z_y = z^2 \\[.5em]
> z=1 \text{ on } C =\{(x,y): y=2x \}
> \end{cases}$$
>   where $C$ is the initial curve of the problem.

**Attempt :**

First of all, we yield the differential problem :

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y^2} = \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^2}$$

We solve :

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y^2} \implies u_1 = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y} = \frac{y-x}{xy} $$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2} - \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y^2} = \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^2} \implies u_2 = \frac{y-x}{xy} -\frac{1}{z} $$

The parameters of the initial curve as a position vector, are : 
$$C : r_C(t) = (x,2x,1) \; x \in \mathbb R$$

And then we yield the system :
$$\begin{cases} Z_1 = \frac{1}{x} \\ Z_2 = \frac{1}{x} - 1 \end{cases} \Rightarrow Z_2 = Z_1 - 1 \implies z_2(x,y,z) = z_1(x,y,z) - 1$$
which finally implies that $z=1$ is a solution but also $z_0 = z(x,y) = z(x,2x) = 1$.

**Question :** Is my approach correct ? Have I left something out of my solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second step seems wrong, by the Lagrange equations $\dfrac{dx}{x^2}-\dfrac{dy}{y^2}=0$, not $=\dfrac{dz}{z^2}$.

You should get something like $u_2=z^{-1}-x^{-1}$, so that then with $u_2=\phi(u_1)$ and inserting the initial conditions one gets
$$
1-x^{-1}=\phi(x^{-1}-(2x)^{-1})\implies \phi(u)=1-2u
$$
and then in general
$$
z^{-1}=x^{-1}+1-2(x^{-1}-y^{-1})\implies z=\frac{xy}{2x-y+xy}.
$$

Comment: By $\dfrac{dx}{x^2}-\dfrac{dy}{y^2}=0$ I would get the same integral curve as $u_1$. How do you yield $u_2$ ?

Comment: From $\dfrac{dz}{z^2}-\dfrac{dx}{x^2}=0$. The situation is quite symmetric in $x,y,z$.

Comment: Oh, I saw the edit now. Yes, yes, got that. I saw that $z^{-2]$ and got dissoriented ! Thanks ! By the way, the "way" you integrate and handle the Lagrange equations can be whatever ? Or should you look for a trick-result in some short that fullfills some cases ?

Comment: In most cases you will not find a nice solution. These are carefully constructed text book exercises that you can manually solve. And in many of these solvable cases there several approaches that may look different at first glance. The geometric object of the characteristic curve is constant, but its description may change.

Comment: Got it ! Thanks for your thorough explanations, they have been the most helpful !

Comment: +1 @LutzL  what do you call Lagrange equation ? i am a bit confused since lagrange is used in many equations...

Comment: The general method of characteristic curves for non-linear 1st order PDE uses the Lagrange-Charpit equations. I have seen the method for linear PDE called Lagrange method resp. the equations in that quotient form Lagrange equations. It seems that it is not widely used.

Comment: Thanks @LutzL.... for these explanations...